# Read PPM image issues

Tags: c++, c, image

I've been having tons of trouble getting my algorithm to succesfully read a PPM image... 
It works perfectly with some images but fails miserably with others, resulting in a half gray (RGB 205, 205, 205) image.

I have tried everything I could find and researched for hours. I've been stuck for a week now...

I hope you guys can help.

```
    Image* pnm_read(char* filePath)
    {
        FILE* file;
        char token[20];
        int imageWidth, imageHeight, maximumColorValue;
        Image* image;

        /* Abre arquivo PNM. */
        file = fopen(filePath, "r");
        if (file == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Não foi possível localizar o arquivo de imagem %s.\n", filePath);
            return 0;
        }

        /* Lê Magic Number do cabecalho e vê se é P6*/
        pnm_get_token(file, token, sizeof token);
        if (strcmp(token, "P6"))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s não é um arquivo PPM válido.\n", filePath);
            fclose(file);
            return 0;
        }

        //Lê widht, height e valor máximo rgb
        if (sscanf(pnm_get_token(file, token, sizeof token), "%d", &imageWidth)        != 1 ||
            sscanf(pnm_get_token(file, token, sizeof token), "%d", &imageHeight)       != 1 ||
            sscanf(pnm_get_token(file, token, sizeof token), "%d", &maximumColorValue) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s não é um arquivo PNM válido.\n", filePath);
            fclose(file);
            return 0;
        }

        //Se não for RGB com componentes de 8 bits (0-255) dá erro
        if (maximumColorValue != 255)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s does not have 8-bit components: maximumColorValue=%d\n", filePath, maximumColorValue);
            fclose(file);
            return 0;
        }

        image = new Image(imageWidth, imageHeight);
        unsigned char* pixelComponents = new unsigned char[imageWidth * imageHeight * 3];
        fread(pixelComponents, sizeof(unsigned char), imageWidth * imageHeight * 3, file);
        fclose(file);

        int r, g, b, pixel;

        for(int i = 3; i <= imageWidth * imageHeight * 3; i += 3)
        {   
            r = pixelComponents[i-3] & 0xff;
            g = pixelComponents[i-2] & 0xff;
            b = pixelComponents[i-1] & 0xff;

            /*fread(&r, sizeof(char), sizeof(char), file);
            fread(&g, sizeof(char), sizeof(char), file);
            fread(&b, sizeof(char), sizeof(char), file);

            r = r & 0xff;
            g = g & 0xff;
            b = b & 0xff;*/

            pixel = (255 << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;             

            // Atribuindo os pixels e virando imagem de cabeca para baixo
            image->pixels[ (imageWidth * imageHeight) - (i/3) - 1] = pixel;
        }

        printf("Lido arquivo PNM (%s): %dx%d pixels.\n", filePath, image->width, image->height);

        return image;
    }
```

Comment: Which kind of images does your code fail?

Comment: Random, downloaded PPM images. But it works (or worked, before I changed it a thousando times to get it working 100%) with at least 1 example I have downloaded here.
It works (or worked) with: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11352921/exempla1b.ppm
It never worked with:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11352921/exempla2b.ppm

Comment: Could you post a printscreen and/or the error message? It would help a lot...

Comment: Hey man. Sure thing. Here are 2 image examples (which are printed on the screen using OpenGL):
http://i.imgur.com/T2SZKic.png

Comment: DCC UFMG is watching you

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code to use structs to aid in comprehension and to assist in debugging.  I've also removed difficult-to-debug snippets like "(imageWidth * imageHeight) - (i/3) - 1"  and introduced some temporary variables to assist, as well.

Some notes: your image pixels seem to include an alpha channel, so I've added one to the RGBA pixel type.  The pragmas also assume consistency with gcc.  I'll assume this is acceptable since the compiler was not mentioned.  Lastly, this example favors readability over efficiency.  There are "better" ways to handle the RGB and RGBA pixel types, but hopefully this will get you started in the right direction.

```
typedef unsigned char u8;   // define a more concise data type

// Save current packing  to ensure the pixel struct is 3 bytes in size
#pragma pack(push)

// Pack on 1-byte boundaries
#pragma pack(1)


typedef struct
{
    u8 red;
    u8 green;
    u8 blue;
    u8 alpha;
} RgbaPixel;

typedef struct
{
    u8 red;
    u8 green;
    u8 blue;
} RgbPixel;

// Restore previous packing
#pragma pack(pop)

Image* pnm_read(char* filePath)
{


    FILE* file = NULL;
    char token[20] = "";
    int imageWidth = 0; 
    int imageHeight = 0;
    int maximumColorValue = 0;
    int numPixels = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    Image* image = NULL;

    /* Abre arquivo PNM. */
    file = fopen(filePath, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Não foi possível localizar o arquivo de imagem %s.\n", filePath);
        return 0;
    }

    /* Lê Magic Number do cabecalho e vê se é P6*/
    pnm_get_token(file, token, sizeof token);
    if (strcmp(token, "P6"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s não é um arquivo PPM válido.\n", filePath);
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }

    //Lê widht, height e valor máximo rgb
    if (sscanf(pnm_get_token(file, token, sizeof token), "%d", &imageWidth)        != 1 ||
        sscanf(pnm_get_token(file, token, sizeof token), "%d", &imageHeight)       != 1 ||
        sscanf(pnm_get_token(file, token, sizeof token), "%d", &maximumColorValue) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s não é um arquivo PNM válido.\n", filePath);
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }

    //Se não for RGB com componentes de 8 bits (0-255) dá erro
    if (maximumColorValue != 255)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s does not have 8-bit components: maximumColorValue=%d\n", filePath, maximumColorValue);
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }

    image = new Image(imageWidth, imageHeight);

    numPixels = imageWidth * imageHeight;
    RgbPixel* pixelComponents = new RgbPixel [numPixels];
    numRead = fread(pixelComponents, sizeof(RgbPixel), numPixels, file);
    fclose(file);

    if (numRead != numPixels)
    {
       // Problem!

       return 0;
    }

    RgbaPixel pixel = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++)
    {   
                pixel.alpha = 255;
        pixel.red = pixelComponents[i].red;
        pixel.green = pixelComponents[i].green;
        pixel.blue = pixelComponents[i].blue;

        // Atribuindo os pixels e virando imagem de cabeca para baixo
        image->pixels[i] = pixel;
    }

    printf("Lido arquivo PNM (%s): %dx%d pixels.\n", filePath, image->width, image->height);

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Wow... Thanks a bunch dude. Nice improvements all along... Sadly, though, the final outcome remains the same. The pixels attribute on my image class is a int array. Could that be the issue? What I'm doing to store those pixels on it is 


int pixel = (int) (pixel.alpha << 24 | pixel.red << 16 | pixel.green << 8 | pixel.blue);

Comment: Your shift-and-OR pixel assignment is accomplished in the first four lines of the for loop (i.e. pixel.alpha = 255,etc).  The generated code should be equivalent, but the struct method is easier to read/debug. How is the pixels attribute organized? Are you sure its ARGB as your shift and OR assignment assumes?  Are you certain that the defect is not in your image viewing process?

Answer (score -1):

Once you correctly read the data from the file (width and height), you could do something like this
(I adapted a code I wrote a while ago):

```
...
for(int i=0; i < height; ++i)
{
    for(int j=0; j < width; ++j)
    {
        // Get pixel index from the PPM data
        int pixelIndex = (i*3) * width + (j*3); 

        int r = pixelComponents[pixelIndex];
        int g = pixelComponents[pixelIndex + 1];
        int b = pixelComponents[pixelIndex + 2];

        // Calc gray value from RGB
        int pixelValue = 0.2126f * r + 0.7152f * g + 0.0722f * b;             

        // Set pixel (i, j) in the output image
        image->pixel[i * width + j] = pixelValue; 
    }
}
...
```

I cannot guarantee the code is correct, but I think it may help you find the solution to your problem.

Good luck!